# Format API Rest for JSON Validated

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, jet-engine

I need to connect a Rest API to WordPress, I'm using JetEngine.

I'm trying to connect, but JetEngine can't identify the API Item Path:

[image: Item Path is not recognized]

I've already used - / , /Veiculos, /Veiculos/Veiculo, All possibilities...

However, the JSON format that the API provides is not valid for JetEngine.

Is there any possibility of redirecting to an external link that returns the API format in the correct JSON?

[image: Format that the API provides]

[image: JSON format valid by Jet Engine]

How can I format this JSON or have JetEngine read this API?

I believe I can play these APIs, format them and then return them to another END POINT. It's possible?